# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' with buildozer when building to android

Tags: python, linux, buildozer

I'm trying to create an android build using buildozer this is the full error

```
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [73 lines of output]
      running dist_info
      creating /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-dipw9cli/sh.egg-info
      writing /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-dipw9cli/sh.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-dipw9cli/sh.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-dipw9cli/sh.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-dipw9cli/sh.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-dipw9cli/sh.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-dipw9cli/sh.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      creating '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-dipw9cli/sh-1.14.3.dist-info'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/ibrahim/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/ibrahim/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/ibrahim/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 366, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 96, in run
          bdist_wheel = self.get_finalized_command('bdist_wheel')
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 304, in get_finalized_command
          cmd_obj = self.distribution.get_command_obj(command, create)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 860, in get_command_obj
          klass = self.get_command_class(command)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 710, in get_command_class
          self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 205, in load
          module = import_module(match.group('module'))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/normal/lib/python3.12/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 27, in <module>
          from .macosx_libfile import calculate_macosx_platform_tag
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3frwh_zs/normal/lib/python3.12/site-packages/wheel/macosx_libfile.py", line 43, in <module>
          import ctypes
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
# Command failed: ['/usr/local/bin/python3.12', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-q', '--user', 'appdirs', 'colorama>=0.3.3', 'jinja2', 'sh>=1.10, <2.0; sys_platform!="win32"', 'build', 'toml', 'packaging', 'setuptools']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/ibrahim-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X415JAB-A416JA:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/14585,unix/ibrahim-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X415JAB-A416JA:/tmp/.ICE-unix/14585'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '1.86.0'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_NAME = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '14546'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     PWD = '/home/ibrahim/VSC/Pygame/PYGAME'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     LOGNAME = 'ibrahim'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE = '/usr/share/code/code'
#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
#     WINDOWPATH = '4'
#     MOTD_SHOWN = 'pam'
#     HOME = '/home/ibrahim'
#     USERNAME = 'ibrahim'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LC_PAPER = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Unity'
#     PYTHONSTARTUP = '/home/ibrahim/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.0.1/pythonFiles/pythonrc.py'
#     GIT_ASKPASS = '/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '8f8183fbd9f54e7f9e238dc88eff2fe8'
#     MANAGERPID = '848'
#     CHROME_DESKTOP = 'code-url-handler.desktop'
#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
#     VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS = ''
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI = 'qemu:///system'
#     USER = 'ibrahim'
#     VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE = '/run/user/1000/vscode-git-02304dc1dc.sock'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '2'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     LC_TIME = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN = '/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:71158'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     GDK_BACKEND = 'x11'
#     HUSHLOGIN = 'FALSE'
#     PATH = '/home/ibrahim/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/ibrahim/.local/bin:/home/ibrahim/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ibrahim/Gradle/gradle-8.5/bin:/home/ibrahim/Gradle/gradle-8.5/bin:/home/ibrahim/Gradle/gradle-8.5/bin:/home/ibrahim/.local/bin/:/home/ibrahim/Gradle/gradle-8.5/bin:/home/ibrahim/.local/bin/'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     MAIL = '/var/mail/ibrahim'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = '40154'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = '/usr/share/applications/code.desktop'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     TERM_PROGRAM = 'vscode'
#     _ = '/home/ibrahim/.local/bin/buildozer'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

From what I understood it's just _cytpes is missing. I searched online and tried the solutions provided such as doing sudo apt install libffi-dev and deleting the ./buildozer and recompiling python by doing ./configure and make and make altinstall. It is still not working